# Increase SEQUENCE by decimal values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### Explanation

I'm trying to automatically fill a column based in a variable step value, but whenever the step is a decimal number, it rounds down.

### Example

If a write `=SEQUENCE(4, 1, 0, A1)` where `A1=0.5`, it should return me:

| Desired values |
| --- |
| 0.0 |
| 0.5 |
| 1.0 |
| 1.5 |

But it rounds down the step to 0 and returns:

| Return |
| --- |
| 0.0 |
| 0.0 |
| 0.0 |
| 0.0 |

Is it right? If it is, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(1:4)*A1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(4, 1, 0, 1)*A1)
```

[image]

Or slightly shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(4, 1, 0)*A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=arrayformula(A1*(sequence(4)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

decimals are not supported under `SEQUENCE`. use:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(4, 1, 0, 1)/2)
```

[image]